# MATLAB Error - Undefined function for input arguments of type 'double'

Tags: function, matlab

Implementing this MATLAB function

```
function y=myfunc(x)
    y=x^2+5*x+6;
end
```

is resulting in the following error.

```
>>myfunc(5)
Undefined function 'myfunc' for input arguments of type 'double'
```

I'm new to MATLAB, and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It's probably wither in a file that is not called "myfunc.m" or not in the same folder where you are

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-functions-in-files.html

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify where you put that function definition.

Answer (score 0):

**You can get results by two methods in matlab**

1. call function and define function below

> ```
> answer= myfunc(5)
>
> function y=myfunc(x)
>
> y=(x^2)+(5*x)+6;
>
> end
> ```

2. a) Second option is to make a new function file but name of function
   and file name should be same

so make a file name as myfunc and write you function code there

> function y=myfunc(x)
>
> ```
> y=(x^2)+(5*x)+6;
>
> end
> ```

- b) in separate file with any name you can call that function

answer= myfunc(5)